# Keep getting empty response when adding place via google place API

Tags: post, go, google-places-api

I'm trying to add a place within app scope via google place API. For this I'm using golang. But I keep on getting no result, there is no error message.

Here is my code

```

```
type latlng struct {
   lat, lng float64
}
type newPlace struct {
   location     latlng
   accuracy     int
   name         string
   phone_number string
   address      string
   types        string
}

func main() {
   requestUrl := "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?key=<MYAPIKEY>"

   obj := newPlace{
      location: latlng{
        lat: 52.1502824,
        lng: 38.2643063,
     },
      name:  "some field",
      types: "storage",
   }

   bodyBytes, err := json.Marshal(&obj)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   body := bytes.NewReader(bodyBytes)
   rsp, err := http.NewRequest("POST", requestUrl, body)
   if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
   }
   defer rsp.Body.Close()

   body_byte, err := ioutil.ReadAll(rsp.Body)
   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }
   fmt.Println(string(body_byte))
}
```

```

Here is the documentation that I followed. https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place

I'm a bit new to golang, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI I wrote [this article](https://juliensalinas.com/en/REST_API_fetching_go_golang_vs_python/) on this touchy topic (JSON data encoded into a POST body request in Go).

You're missing 4 things here:

- the `http.Client` creation. Then you need to execute the request you're preparing with `http.NewRequest` by using `client.Do`.
- add `json` fields to your struct and export variables contained in struct by capitalizing variables's first letters
- set `Content-Type` to `application/json`
- Google is expecting an array instead of a string in `types`, so I replace with an array containing 1 string (but you should adapt this depending on how many types you want to pass to Google)

Here is a working script:

```
type latlng struct {
    Lat float64 `json:"lat"`
    Lng float64 `json:"lng"`
}

type newPlace struct {
    Location    latlng    `json:"location"`
    Accuracy    int       `json:"accuracy"`
    Name        string    `json:"name"`
    PhoneNumber string    `json:"phone_number"`
    Address     string    `json:"address"`
    Types       [1]string `json:"types"`
}

func main() {
    requestUrl := "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?key=<your key>"

    types := [1]string{"storage"}
    obj := newPlace{
        Location: latlng{
            Lat: 52.1502824,
            Lng: 38.2643063,
        },
        Name:  "some field",
        Types: types,
    }

    bodyBytes, err := json.Marshal(&obj)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    body := bytes.NewReader(bodyBytes)
    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", requestUrl, body)
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    rsp, err := client.Do(req)
    defer rsp.Body.Close()

    body_byte, err := ioutil.ReadAll(rsp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(body_byte))
}
```

Hope it's working now !

Comment: Thanks, but now I get an an invalid request as a response. Do you have any idea why I'm not getting a ok response?

Comment: {
        "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
    }

Comment: This time I think the error might come from content-type. You should set it to json, which is not the case by default using NewRequest("POST",...). Let me check

Comment: I tried both, with and without content type, but to no avail. This is how I did it.
`req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")`

Comment: ok just found the problem at last ! Editing my answer right now :) (this is about your `Types` which sould be an array, not a string)

Comment: Hmm, does it work for you? I still getting the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159416/discussion-between-julien-salinas-and-ivan-marchenko).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to marshall objects to JSON which have no exported fields, so the resulting JSON document is empty. [Per the JSON documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal), it will only marshall exported fields (those whose names begin with a capital letter). Try:

```
type latlng struct {
   Lat float64 `json:"lat"`
   Lng float64 `json:"lng"`
}

type newPlace struct {
   Location     latlng `json:"location"`
   Accuracy     int `json:"accuracy"`
   Name         string `json:"name"`
   PhoneNumber string `json:"phone_number"`
   Address      string `json:"address"`
   Types        string `json:"types"`
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, but I'm still getting same error `{
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}`. Could it be because I'm not specifying content type?

Comment: I don't know, what happens if you specify it?